# How to run scheduled task only once in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run scheduled tasks only once at the specific time but I couldn't figure out how to do that. All I understand is, every 10 seconds 1 task is stored and then when the time comes job runs them all.(I shared the result in below.) For example test_1 task scheduled to 11:02. I started code at 11:01. So for 60 seconds I got 6 results.

For second scheduled task 120 seconds passed since the beginning so I got 12 results.

Sorry for the misinformation. I updated my question. I also shared my excel date list I hope this gives more information.If today is work day (1) then run scheduled tasks else do nothing.This code will run nonstop so I have to check the current date. This is why I placed schedule inside the while loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import schedule 

def test_1():
    print("do task 1")

def test_2():
    print("do task 2")

while(1 != 2):

     today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

     df_Calender = pd.read_excel('Calender.xlsx', sheet_name=0) 

     date = df_Calender['Date'] #Date column

     filter_1 = date == today
     df1_Calender = df_Calender.loc[filter_1]

     week_day = df1_Calender['WeekDays']

     if (week_day.item() != 1):
        print("do nothing")
     else:
        schedule.every().day.at("11:02").do(test_1)
        schedule.every().day.at("11:03").do(test_2)

        time.sleep(10)

        schedule.run_pending()
```

Here is the date list(Calender.xlsx)

[image]

This is the result

```
do task 1
do task 1
do task 1
do task 1
do task 1
do task 1
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
do task 2
```

Comment: why do you schedule multiple times the same task? if you want them only once get rid of the infinite while loop, to the tasks will be ascheduled only once.

Comment: I think you just want to move the scheduling outside of the loop. Every loop you schedule more tasks to be executed

Comment: Whats your operating system? If it is unix based, you could make use of the integrated "crontab" to schedule the job via the operating system. You can then have your Python code in a script, which will then be called by the crontab (OS according to the defined schedule. Link: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: I have date list which I didn't share. I am checking date from there and if the date matches, I will run these scheduled tasks. To check the current date I need while loop. This code will run for a year without shutting it down.

Comment: could you edit your code to include that list of dates and briefly explain what you are trying to do? is this list of dates the times where you want the task to run or when you want the task schedule to be created? You most likely don't need a loop the way you have it now.

Comment: It is the times where I want the task to run. I am sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to move your `schedule` out of the `while` loop, otherwise, it will keep scheduling the task after every 10-seconds due to the `time.sleep(10)` in the endless loop.

You can try something like:

```
def task1():
   # Do something

schedule.every().day.at("11:02").do(task1)

# If you only want it to run once, then no loop is required
# Else if you want it to run once per day then add the while True loop
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. But it's what I understood you want

You have a list of times when you want a certain function to be called.

In this example you want task1 to be executed at 3 different times of the day and task 2 at times of the day

```
task1_schedule = ["11:02", "13:30", "17:00"]
task2_schedule = ["11:03", "14:20"]
```

Then you just iterate over the list and set a schedule

```
for start_time in task1_schedule:
    schedule.every().day.at(start_time).do(test_1)

for start_time in task2_schedule:
    schedule.every().day.at(start_time).do(test_2)
```

In this case since there are only 2 different taks I made 2 different list.

This code will create the schedules for each task once for each element in your schedule list.

Answer (score 0):

Since your calls to schedule are inside while loop, they get placed on schedule multiple times. You need to place items on schedule once and only check if they are scheduled in loop. Try moving both schedule lines in front of while loop.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import schedule 

def test_1():
   print("do task 1")

def test_2():
   print("do task 2")

schedule.every().day.at("11:02").do(test_1)
schedule.every().day.at("11:03").do(test_2)

while(1 != 2):
   time.sleep(10)

   schedule.run_pending()
```

See this [example](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-every-x-minute) in documentation.

---

Based on comment you also need to check date before running task. I advise not to schedule conditionally, but to check for date either inside `test_1` and `test_2` functions or specify more day/week conditions (for example `.every(3).days` for each third day).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Just adding `schedule.clear()` after `schedule.run_pending()` clears all stored tasks and leaves only one scheduled job. Thank you for your help.